# WPF Parent event handler using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

It seems that I would like to the opposite of the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618315/bind-a-parent-windows-event-to-usercontrol-inner-handlers-with-mvvm). I have a WPF application that uses the MVVM pattern. The main view determines the view to be displayed with

```
<!-- Content -->
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Where CurrentView is the "current" view. In this same main view model I also have buttons that are enabled an disabled via a bind to "IsValid" on the view model

```
<Button Content="{x:Static r:Resources.Next}" Background="LawnGreen"
                Command="{Binding NextCommand,Mode=OneWay}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsValid,Mode=TwoWay}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsNextVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

This has a simple implementation like:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentView.IsValid;
    }
    set
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

But you will notice that the "IsValid" flag comes from whatever is the CurrentView. Thus each view determines if it is valid or not.
In one of these views (UserControls) I have a ComboBox that when something is selected the "IsValid" for that view should go from false to true. This looks like:

```
private Client selectedItem;
public Client SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        selectedItem = value;
        IsValid = true;
        ProvisionService.SelectedClient = selectedItem;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsValid");
    }
}

private bool _isValid;
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return _isValid;
    }
    set
    {
        _isValid = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The problem that I am seeing is that parent doesn't seem to be seeing the event that has changed from false to true in the child view. How do I notify the parent that this property in the child has changed?

Here is the implementation of CurrentView

```
private IProvisionView _currentView;
public IProvisionView CurrentView
{
    get { return _currentView; }
    set
    {
        _currentView = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsPrevVisible));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsNextVisible));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsHomeVisible));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same what WPF does. Assign to the PropertyChanged event.
If your CurrentView is set:

```
// old (if assigned)
_currentView.PropertyChanged -= CurrentView_PropertyChanged;
// new
value.PropertyChanged += CurrentView_PropertyChanged;
```

and then check if it was the IsValid property

Comment: I am afraid that I don’t understand this proposed solution. The child view model raises the property changed event. This view model has no knowledge that it is a child and doesn’t have access to the parent property “CurrentView”. As it is the view model of the “CurrentView”. For example I have AView and BView with view models AViewModel and BViewModel. Both views have an IsValid property that is bound to a property on each of the view models. As shown in the problem description an event is currently raised for changing this. There is also an EventHandler on the parent view model?

Comment: @KevinBurton: How is the `CurrentView` property in the view model implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the `CurrentView` property is set to a new value in the parent view model, you should hook up an event handler to the child view model's `PropertyChanged` event and handle it by raising the `PropertyChanged` event for the `IsValid` property of the parent view model that the `Button` is bound to, e.g.:

```
private INotifyPropertyChanged _currentView;
public INotifyPropertyChanged CurrentView
{
    get { return _currentView; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentView != null)
            _currentView.PropertyChanged -= OncurrentViewPropertyChanged;
        _currentView = value;
        if (_currentView != null)
            _currentView.PropertyChanged += OncurrentViewPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OncurrentViewPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsValid") // = nameof(ChildViewModel.IsValid)
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsValid"); // = nameof(IsValid)
}
```

Comment: And check inside OncurrentViewPropertyChanged if the property was "IsValid". (is in eventargs e)

Comment: @Klamsi: Yes, that's a nice thing to do as well. I edited my answer to include this.